# Installing ImageMagick php extension on centOS results error

Tags: php, linux, centos, imagemagick, imagick

Well I'm trying to install ImageMagick on my centOS server.

The steps I took before getting the error:

```
# yum install gcc php-devel php-pear

# yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel

# pecl install imagick <-- GIVES ME ERROR
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: honorsbaseinstall in Role.php on line 180

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: installable in Role.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: phpfile in Role.php on line 212

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: config_vars in Role.php on line 49

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/Command.php on line 259

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command.php on line 259 XML Extension not found
```

Thank you !

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/589877/pecl-command-produces-long-list-of-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note using the php56w version of php pear when reinstalling (instead of the stock php-pear package). So in short :
1. yum erase php-pear
2. rm -rf /usr/share/pear/
3. yum install php56w-pear